# How to add snooze effect once a notification is delivered in ios 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10, usernotifications

I am implementing UserNotification in my app. When the notification gets fired it shows two action, in one i want to add snooze effect, it must snooze after 5 mins again. How to handle it ? thanks for all ! help if any one do have idea

Comment: How you are going to add snooze button there.. From notification or after opening notification

Comment: when the notification is delivered i handle it by a AlertController,with two action 1.) Close 2.) Snooze

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For iOS10, use this code.

Use this code in `AppDelegate.swift` file.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "identifier", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [])
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert , .sound]) { (greanted, error) in
            print(error)
    }
    return true
}
```

You can put this code in any view controller.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent.init()
content.title = "Notification Title"
content.subtitle = "Notification Sub-Title"
content.body = "Notification Body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in 
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    if (error != nil){
        //handle here
    }
}
```

You can handle notification using following method:

```
extension UIViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
        completionHandler( [.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
        print("Tapped in notification")
    }
}
```

You can use this [Blog](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/22/23-notifications-in-ios-10/) as reference and [Example](https://github.com/swiftingio/blog/tree/%2323-Notifications-in-iOS-10).

Comment: The question is not about how to create a notification but snoozing it

Answer (score 0):

Well to snooze notification you can create another notification with same details of current notification and increase the fire date by 5 mins.

Here is the code I used :

```
func snoozeScheduledNotification(notification:UILocalNotification) -> Void {
    // Snooze for 10 mins
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = notification.fireDate?.addingTimeInterval(60*10) 
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: 0) // 0 = No Repeat
    localNotification.alertBody = notification.alertBody
    localNotification.soundName = notification.soundName
    localNotification.userInfo = notification.userInfo  
    localNotification.category = notification.category
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i want to schedule it  Using  UserNotification Framework only for ios 10

Comment: When the user selects a snooze button in the notification, the app will call the delegate method to handle so just call this function in it.

Comment: what if there is no snooze button in the notification.? What if the notification fires and then you are routed to an alarm screen where you can snooze it from there?

Comment: Just call it on click of the button then.

Comment: This is deprecated anyways

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and simplest code I found about it

For Swift 3/4

```
extension UNNotification {
    func snoozeNotification(for hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        content.title = "Another Alert"
        content.body = "Your message"
        content.sound = .default()

        let identifier = self.request.identifier
        guard let oldTrigger = self.request.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger else {
            debugPrint("Cannot reschedule notification without calendar trigger.")
            return
        }

        var components = oldTrigger.dateComponents
        components.hour = (components.hour ?? 0) + hours
        components.minute = (components.minute ?? 0) + minutes
        components.second = (components.second ?? 0) + seconds

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Rescheduling failed", error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                debugPrint("rescheduled success")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You just need to call it this way :

```
response.notification.snoozeNotification(for: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 30)
```

Credit goes to **Simon Ljungberg** : https://gist.github.com/simme/96264d5ceee394083d18e2c64f42a3a9